# Ionic 2 starters qns on tutorial

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Hi I'm new to ionic 2 and I'm unsure of some of the following code in my .html file under my (page)

```
<ion-content padding class="getting-started"> //Question 1

     <h3>Hello World!</h3>

<p>
     My learning login page
</p>
<p>
     <button primary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button> //Question 2
</p>

</ion-content>
```

As follows,

on Question 1)

What does --> padding class="getting-started" <-- defines?

If it was written like --> class="getting-started" <-- I will understand that it is pointing to a class in the css file.

---

Question 2)

What does --> primary menuToggle <-- does?

I mean, I am unsure if menuToggle is a built-in function, and why is there a primary before menuToggle.

If it's a function, where is it pointing to?

---

UPDATE*

I realise that all css have to be linked via /app/theme/app.core.scss before it could work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *primary* and *padding* are css properties of ionic

Take a look at the documentation for theming for more information on how to use them and what each of them do: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/

Comment: thanks!! also may i check with you, how do i direct my page to the right css file? It seem to be matching with the wrong css file

Comment: if you're using sass you only use ionic.app.scss file in scss folder, otherwise you have to include the css files in the index; (also, if the answer suited you're question, please mark it as accepted)

Comment: Sorry I realize that I have to import every css into app.core.scss instead